# How to fix Tag Checker in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a **tag checker** for a game where you can find allies and enemies but when I add `else` at the end is shows everyone as the enemy. I have the enemy list but it's too big to write them all...
How can I get this work properly?

```
if (document.getElementById("tagcheck").value == "WCT") {
        //document.getElementById("tagcheck").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("checker").value = "FRIEND";
        document.getElementById("checker").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }

                if (document.getElementById("tagcheck").value == "WeUSA") {
        //document.getElementById("tagcheck").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("checker").value = "FRIEND";
        document.getElementById("checker").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }

                if (document.getElementById("tagcheck").value == "x114x") {
        //document.getElementById("tagcheck").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("checker").value = "FRIEND";
        document.getElementById("checker").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }

                if (document.getElementById("tagcheck").value == "YPJ") {
        //document.getElementById("tagcheck").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("checker").value = "FRIEND";
        document.getElementById("checker").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }

    // Enemy tags

     else if (document.getElementById("tagcheck").value.length == 0 ) {
        document.getElementById("checker").value = "ERROR";
        document.getElementById("checker").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }

        else {
            document.getElementById("checker").value = "ENEMY";
            document.getElementById("checker").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        return false;

};
```

Comment: I mean, if the `tagcheck` value is not `YPJ` and does have a value, it's going to go into the final else.  The top three `if` blocks do not prevent that final else from happening.

Comment: Why not just make them all distinct if blocks? This way instead of else at the bottom, you can have a tighter check on the else conditions to ensure tag with id "checker" does not automatically get assigned the value and red background color. Right now, it appears to default to else if the other conditions fail hence the result you must be seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `else if` come from nowhere...
I suppose you are looking for that ?

```
const tagCheck = document.getElementById('tagcheck')
  ,   eChecker = document.getElementById('checker')
  ,   friendsTags = [ 'WCT', 'WeUSA', 'x114x', 'YPJ' ]
  ;
function XYZ ()
  {
  if (friendsTags.includes( tagCheck.value )) 
    {
    //tagCheck.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    eChecker.value = 'FRIEND';
    eChecker.style.backgroundColor = 'green';      
    }
  else if (tagCheck.value.length == 0 )
    {
    eChecker.value = "ERROR";
    eChecker.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
  else
    {
    eChecker.value = "ENEMY";
    eChecker.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  return false;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!! this work perfect, just as i wanted to!!